# remove logging from release apk file using gradle

Tags: android, gradle

I am trying to remove logging from the release apk file. I followed the advice of using `BuildConfig.DEBUG` variable, which will be true for debug builds and false otherwise.

In a Constants file, I have:

```
public static final LOG_ENABLED = BuildConfig.DEBUG;
```

And then I check the variable before logging.

```
if(Constants.LOG_ENABLED){
   // print Log
}
```

Then, in the `gradle` build file, I have added android

`{ buildTypes { release { minifyEnabled true shrinkResources true } } }` . I then ran `gradle assembleRelease`, but the logging still remains inside the apk file?

Can someone kindly show me the error of my ways?

Comment: seems this will remove the logs for log.d() alone

Comment: Unfortunately, even the log.d is not being deleted. It seems I'm doing something fundamentally wrong.

Comment: check if this link helps  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9855834/when-does-adt-set-buildconfig-debug-to-false

Comment: still if you are logging based on a boolean you can set that variable LOG_ENABLED to false before taking release apk

Answer (score 0):

- in general now I would go with [this solution] [0](https://tekeye.uk/android/examples/android-debug-vs-release-build)
- in your snippet I think you may have to explicit the `boolean` type:

  `public static final boolean LOG_ENABLED = BuildConfig.DEBUG;`

to have it working, as in these other answers: [[1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12458918/4092588)], [[2](https://www.jianshu.com/p/3eaa272dd1ac)]

- historically `BuildConfig.DEBUG;` has been affected by [known issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9855834/when-does-adt-set-buildconfig-debug-to-false/29266076#29266076) - also [with libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20617949/4092588) - and a solution for both Eclipse and Android Studio can be found for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29266076/4092588)